# Samba Share writable for everyone

Tags: networking, permissions, kubuntu, samba

I can't get my samba share to work. 
My intention is to host a directory which is writable for everyone (including guests). For this pupose, I created a user and a group who owns the corresponding directory:

```
drwxrwsr-x 19 transferuser transfergroup  4096  Dez 14 12:43 Transfer
```

In my smb.conf I've tried dozens of configuraton combinations I found in several threads. I can browse the directory and read all files but I have no write access. I browse the directory from a machine running Kubuntu 19.10 using Dolphin. The server also runs Kubuntu 19.10. Oringinally I thought that `fource user` and `force group` would automatically apply the unix rights for this user. But this user has full access since he owns the directory. How can I allow write access for every user (and guests)?
This is my smb.conf at the moment:

```
[global]
  security = user
  map to guest = bad user
  unix extensions = no

[...]

[Transfer]
path=/media/shared/6TB2/Transfer/
read only = no
comment=
force user = transferuser
force group = transfergroup
writable = yes
browsable = yes
public = yes
create mask = 775
force create mode = 775
security mask = 775
force security mode = 775
directory mask = 2775
force directory mode = 2775
directory security mask = 2775
force directory security mode = 2775
inherit permissions = yes
```

Edit 1:
The share was created by editing smb.conf. The output of `net usershare info --long` is **empty**. The output of `testparm -s` is:

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Unknown parameter encountered: "usershare_acl"
Ignoring unknown parameter "usershare_acl"
Unknown parameter encountered: "usershare_acl"
Ignoring unknown parameter "usershare_acl"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

# Global parameters
[global]
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        logging = file
        map to guest = Bad User
        max log size = 1000
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        security = USER
        server min protocol = SMB2
        server role = standalone server
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        unix password sync = Yes
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        idmap config * : backend = tdb


[printers]
        browseable = No
        comment = All Printers
        create mask = 0700
        path = /var/spool/samba
        printable = Yes


[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/printers


[Transfer]
        comment = Transfer for all
        force group = transfergroup
        force user = transferuser
        guest ok = Yes
        path = /media/shared/6TB2/Transfer/
        read only = No

[...]
```

Comment: "force user = transferuser" should have done it by itself. Did you also create the share in Dolphin? THat may be the problem. Edit your original post and add the output of the following command - without quotes: "net usershare info --long"